# How can i check if a time has expired?

Tags: php

How can i check if the duration has exceeded the current date/time? I'm not sure how to implement this with the date function?

```
//date item was put up for sale
$start_date = date("2018-05-24");

//time it was put up for sale
$start_time = date('08:37:19');

//The duration the item should be up until
$duration = date('2018-05-25 09.00.00');
```

Comment: `date` takes a format specifier, like `H:i:s`, and returns a string with the date formatted according to that specifier. Numbers don't do anything in that formatting, so `date('2018-05-24")` just returns `"2018-05-24"` as is…

Comment: There are examples at PHPs [DateTime::diff manual page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current date, you just need to use `date` function with format in parameter:

`date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

After, you just need to compare current with your date.

Here some examples:

`date("Y-m-d") == $start_date` (returns `true`)

`date("Y-m-d H:i:s") < $duration` (returns `false`)

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
Try this:

```
if (strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) >= strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$start_date $start_time")) && strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) <= strtotime($duration)) {
 return true;
} else {
 return false;
}
```

Comment: You're comparing *strings* using `>=`/`<=`…!?

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to use timestamps

```
$startTime = strtotime('2015-01-01 00:00:00');
$dateExpire = strtotime('+5 day', $startTime);

if($dateExpire <= time()) {
    return 'expired';
}
```